# MySQL: Granting permission for CREATE VIEW

Tags: permissions, mysql-5.6

I created a new database schema as 'company_security' and populate the database with the table structure of very popular Company-Employee tables which contains DEPARTMENT,DEPENDENT,DEPT_LOCATIONS,EMPLOYEE,PROJECT & WORKS_ON tables. Then I created a new user in a root user session as,

`CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password1'`

What I wanted to do is create a view WORKS_ON1(Fname,Lname,Pno) on EMPLOYEE and WORKS_ON from user1. To do this, first I granted necessary permission as root to user1 as follows.

```
GRANT SELECT ON company_security.WORKS_ON TO 'user1'@'localhost'
GRANT SELECT company_security.EMPLOYEE TO 'user1'@'localhost' 
GRANT CREATE VIEW ON company_security.* TO 'user1'@'localhost'
```

Then I flushed the privileges and this was the output for `SHOW GRANTS for 'user1'@'localhost'`

[image: output for SHOW GRANTS]

Then I tried to create the view from user1 as,

```
CREATE VIEW WORKS_ON1 AS select Fname,Lname,Pno from EMPLOYEE,WORKS_ON;
```

but I got an error like this,

```
ERROR 1142 (42000): CREATE VIEW command denied to user 'user1'@'localhost' for table 'WORKS_ON1'
```

I have found a similar [problem](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,224573) in MySQL forum but the MySQL DOC reference link he mentioned in the solution seems like removed.

So my question is how to solve this problem? even I tried to solve this by granting permission for create view in a global level for user1 but that failed too. Either we cannot grant permission for the WORKS_ON1 view as the error saying because it does not exist in the database already.

MySQL version I'm using: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.28, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is detailed in [When Privilege Changes Take Effect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-changes.html) in the MySQL documentation.

> A grant table reload affects privileges for each existing client
>   connection as follows:
>
> Table and column privilege changes take effect with the client's next
>   request.
>
> Database privilege changes take effect the next time the client
>   executes a USE db_name statement.
>
> Note Client applications may cache the database name; thus, this
>   effect may not be visible to them without actually changing to a
>   different database or flushing the privileges.
>
> Global privileges and passwords are unaffected for a connected client.
>   These changes take effect only for subsequent connections.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution from the MySQL script generated by [forward engineering](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-forward-engineering-live-server.html).

I was getting the same error as yours:

> SELECT * FROM og_erp.sellerlist   Error Code: 1142. SELECT command denied to user 'user1'@'localhost' for table 'sellerlist'  0.000 sec

when creating the view:

```
CREATE
VIEW sellerList
AS
SELECT SellerName FROM og_erp.seller;
```

The solution is to create a place holder table, with schema as of view:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Placeholder table for view `og_erp`.`sellerList`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS og_erp.sellerList (
  SellerName VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Grant CREATE VIEW, DROP on the place holder table to the user
[image: Grant privileges]

Also give SELECT privilege on place holder table, if you want that user is able to SELECT from the view, rather than getting following error:

> 12:32:05  SELECT * FROM og_erp.sellerlist Error Code: 1142. SELECT command denied to user 'user1'@'localhost' for table 'sellerlist'  0.000 sec

Now, View can be created by the user as follows,

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS og_erp.sellerlist;
CREATE
VIEW sellerList
AS
SELECT SellerName FROM og_erp.seller;
```

> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS og_erp.sellerlist    0 row(s) affected   0.047 sec

> CREATE VIEW sellerList AS SELECT SellerName FROM og_erp.seller    0 row(s) affected   0.000 sec

> SELECT * FROM og_erp.sellerlist   1 row(s) returned   0.000 sec / 0.000 sec